# Is it possible to predict/forecast results of pairwise comparison matrices based on one or two initial samples?

Tags: forecasting, multiple-comparisons

I'm curious if it's possible to predict the results of a pairwise comparison matrix that will be sent out to 100 people based on the results of one or two filled out surveys?

**The matrix has the following format:**

```
Indicators    Var_1    Var_2    .....    Var_n
Var_1         NA
Var_2                  NA
.....                           NA
Var_N                                    NA
```

There are three ways to to fill this survey:

1. column more important
2. Column and row are equally important
3. row more important

I have received 2 filled out surveys so far and just wondering if from those 2 results I can predict how the results will look like for the 100?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: generally, no, you wouldn't expect to be able to reliably predict how 100 people will perform such a task based on two examples.

There are exceptions, but you would normally have no way of knowing you're in one until you've seen a lot more than two.